# VB.NET - Can I send a reference to a WinForm control object to a subroutine?

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview, datagrid

I have a WinForm that contains several DataGrids (all with identical column names and column count).  I would like to have a single subroutine which can manipulate data in any of the DataGridView objects in my class.

To accomplish this, is there a way to pass a reference to a WinForm object to a VB.NET subroutine?

Here's my current code.  In this example, the DataGridView object (dgvServersServices) is being accessed directly rather than being passed in as a variable:

```
Private Sub populate_data_grid(system_name As String, system_type As String)
    dgvServers.Rows.Clear()
    dgvServers.Rows.Add(New String() {system_name, system_type})
    dgvServers.AutoResizeColumns()
    dgvServers.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)

End Sub
```

Comment: Add ByRef before the parameter name, but don't use ref when you call the method.

Comment: `Private Sub populate_data_grid(system_type As String, forGrid As DataGridView)`  Use forGrid in place of dgvServersServices in your routine.

Comment: @N0Alias   He is using VB so the parameters are already passed by ref when passing objects.  the byref will actually pass the pointer by ref and you will have a pointer to a pointer to an object.  Byref is really only needed with strings and Int types.

Comment: @Kevbo So you're saying that I can pass the object to the subroutine normally & it will already be a reference?

Comment: Yes.  LarsTech gave you a sample of the function declaration. VB defaults to byref when passing objects.  just replace all your direct grid names with the name of the parameter as lars said above.

Comment: Arguments that are Reference Types are already passed ByRef so no need to specify this

Comment: @MattWilko, that is not the case. Everything is passed by value unless the parameter is declared `ByRef`. What I think you're actually referring to, although inaccurately, is that you already access reference type objects via a reference, so you are actually passing a reference by value rather than passing an object by value. You can pass an object by value (`ByVal p As SomeStructure`), a reference by value (`ByVal p As SomeClass`), an object by reference (`ByRef p As SomeStructure`) or a reference by reference (`ByRef p As SomeClass`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's comments.  I learned that in VB.NET, object parameters are automatically passed to subroutines as a reference, So the parameter can represent any existing and accessible instance of that object type.

Here is the working code:

```
Private Sub populate_data_grid(system_name As String, 
                               system_type As String, 
                               dgv As DataGridView)
    dgv.Rows.Clear()
    dgv.Rows.Add(New String() {system_name, system_type})
    dgv.AutoResizeColumns()
    dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
End Sub
```